# Magento 2: Send Email REST API

Tags: rest, api, magento2

How can I build `REST API` for sending email?

As example build it as :

```
/V1/email/send/?username=aaa@example.com&message=text
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento2 can not send custom emails in API.
But the basic interface will have an e-mail notification

E.g

```
  API:POST /V1/order/{orderId}/ship
```

the parameter can be set

```
{ 
...
"notify": true,
...
}
```